# How to solve JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal, in this code

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner at **JSON** document, this is my code so please help me to solve this error.

```json
{
"_id": "_design/utilisateur",
"_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d",
"views":
  {
    "tous": {
        "map": "function(doc){if (doc.role=='ut....  ]])}}"
    },
    "3500": {
        "map": "function(doc) {if (doc.role=='ut... )}}"
    },
    "distancetot": {
        "map": "function(doc) {var somme= ... eur'){ 
emit(doc._id, somme);
    }
}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this an example of document:
{
   "_id": "4d760d44992fddfeea9db3bf7b000410",
   "_rev": "4-f71ada20d95807b78f7e791e40aff2b4",
   "role": "utilisateur",
   "distancet0": 1000,
   "distancet1": 260,
   "distancet2": 1600,
   "distancet3": 2700,
   "distancet4": 1950
}

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you have a control character within a string literal, for instance, character code 8 or 10 or 13 or anything below 32 (a space).

[The JSON definition](http://json.org) tells us that you cannot have literal control characters in string literals, you must use an escape sequence such as `\b`, `\r`, `\n`, or `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is a hex code for a Unicode "code point" (character).

So for instance, pretend the following is in a file (or other data stream):

```
{
    "property": "value with an invalid
control character in it"
}
```

That's invalid JSON, the string literal starting with `"value` has at least one control character in it (the line break, might be one or two control characters depending on the OS).

This is how we would fix it:

```
{
    "property": "value with an valid\nescape sequence in it"
}
```

Note the `\n` where the line break used to be.

You can use http://jsonlint.com to validate JSON, it's quite good at pointing out where the error is.

---

Re your edit: It is indeed a line break causing the problem:

```
"distancetot": {
    "map": "function(doc) {var somme= Math.abs(doc.distancet0-    doc.distancet1); if(doc.role=='utilisateur'){ 
Error is here -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The line break after `if(doc.role=='utilisateur'){` is an invalid control character, just as in my example above.