# spring mvc json response to ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, spring

i have an issue with json parsing SyntaxError: "**JSON.parse: bad escaped character**" while proceeding an ajax success : to be clear this is the ajax code :

```
 $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
        url : '/cart/add',
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data : $(this).serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(content) {
            $("#result").append(content.addToCartLayer);
            $.fancybox({
                href : '#result',
                showCloseButton : false,
                enableEscapeButton : false,
                hideOnOverlayClick:false
            });
        },
        error : function(xht, status, ex) {
            console.log("error : " + ex);//JSON.parse: bad escaped character
        }
    });
```

}

and the java code is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public String addToCart(@RequestParam("productCodePost") final String code, final Model model,
        @Valid final AusAddToCartForm form, final BindingResult bindingErrors, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel)
{
    // MY LOGIC HERE
    return ControllerConstants.Views.Fragments.Cart.AddToCartPopup;
}
```

well the story begins by adding a prodcut to the cart that has a specific "size = XL" and "color = RED ", every thing goes fine until i've changed the color value , eg "R'NB" and the ajax exception was throwen (JSON.parse: bad escaped character)

i tried to add the `@ResponseBody` to my method but have no  result .

So this is my question , if you need more clarification please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there's an invalid character in the new color value: "R'NB". JSON can't handle the ' character. 
Please take a look here: [How to solve JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal, in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code) 
Hopefully this answers your question.