# JSON.parse() wont accept valid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, compiler-errors

I am trying to parse the following string: `{"text":"Hej"}`, in JS

This is valid JSON. It's a property on an object. But when I try to parse it, I get the following error: [image: JSON ERROR]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your issue isn't reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/mr7ssLk7/

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Then your string contains a control character.. (who would have guessed haha) Do a simple test on the json-string > how many characters is it (and how many do you expect)? Then find out the character-code of character 13.. `str.charCodeAt(13)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code

Comment: Look for the mystery character: `console.log(encodeURIComponent(yourString))`

Comment: `//Function for converting JSON into HTML
function extractFeedContent(str) {

 /*if(str.hasOwnProperty("text")) {
  console.log("My god! There was text!");
 }*/
console.log(encodeURIComponent(str));
 return JSON.parse(str);
 

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.. your string isn't valid (for JSON): it contains a control character at position 13. 
Have a look for yourself: `json_str.charCodeAt(13)` and compare with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes .

Edit: seems like you had a  Line Feed = (LF) = `\n` in there.

Comment: It says "10" in the console

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it now!

It was a line break, as you can see here:

[image]

I will replace line breaks with `<br />`

**Thank so much everybody for the help!**

Answer (score 0):

For any future members also getting the issue, here's my problem in depth and how to possibly fix it.

I allowed users to write whatever they wanted in a textarea, and that would be via AJAX inserted into my `statuses` MySQL table, without escaping any characters like `\n` or others. This is bad practice and may lead to issues like this.

How to fix it then..

Best practice is to escape it PHP. And it couldn't be simpler, just use the built-in PHP function: `nl2br`. This will replace all linebreaks with `<br />`. Here's an example:

```
$str = "Bar bar ba r foo foo foof foo bar
bar bar bar fooo
more foo foofo bar foo bar";

$new_string = nl2br($str);
```

If you are a little late to the party, and only realizing this issue a little to late, you can do it in JavaScript too! Like so:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Just remeber to this before parsing JSON or anything like that. As JSON will error.

Hope it helped you, happy developing!!