# Ajax call promise is not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, debugging

I am making an AJAX call to a REST API in my javascript code. The call basically fetches a JSON file. The AJAX call is something like this:

```
$.ajax(ajaxObj).then(function(response) {}).catch(function(err) {});
```

So, the network monitor shows status 200 for this call but the JSON response shows the following error :

> SyntaxError:JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line x and column y of the JSON data.

Basically the response is an invalid JSON. Using `debugger` I noticed that the control never enters the `then()` block despite status 200 and thus the control is going into the catch block. Why is that so and how can I resolve it?

Comment: can you show the code of your ajax call?

Comment: The ajax call is going through as i am getting status 200 OK and response as well. So i guess there is nothing wrong with the ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your JSON data is misformated . Check for cariage returns in middle of strings or other invalids characters in your JSON response.

(May be related to [How to solve JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal, in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are expecting a JSON string with `ajaxObj`, and the error states that you have an error in your JSON syntax, you should check the returning JSON if it was parsed properly. Your server can return 200 code and still return an invalid JSON within the body.

Not sure, but perhaps this can help: paste your returning JSON [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Comment: Yes, it is returning an invalid JSON.

Comment: So, the ajax promise is not getting resolved because of the invalid JSON response. And does that mean, unless the JSON file is modified inside the API, there is nothing i can do about it?

Comment: If you have no access to modify the API response, then the answer is no. There is one 'hacky way', but I wouldn't recommend it, and not sure if it would really work. That is to try to catch a response in some other way, and parse it your self. But as mentioned, this is very very very bad practice, do not try to do this unless you really have to, and only if this is one single specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ajax call returns an invalid JSON, the control will not enter the then() block. To handle errors you have to use done() and fail() methods.

```
    $.ajax("url").done(() => { 
      //success
    }).fail(() => { 
      //error
    })
```

Inside the error you can resolve the promise. Hope it helps.