# ERROR when Parsing JSON Array as a JSON Object

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, ejs

I'm trying to convert **news** into **json** in **EJS** but I'm getting this error:

```
JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 491 of the JSON data
```

My code in EJS:

```
var news = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(news) %>');
```

My JSON when I just use JSON.stringify(news):

```
[{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AL8lKjMTbG3Cwo5S_mSyJIgnnTSnG5CShXJluGQmCXZQem2HZJYO3Xni6oi7YkO1bf0AiPEzctP9t7p4iXohF_oSmh4lekT6N4_Xi_3FsOwFL7v0aGYESdS7Hwy0ljNy94xgSIa-p44jadT8K72ncdZLathEWT9VLdgFzKPyIbWNdfzXjna8ZZ-l0MnFGvP7ctxpUmlnS0bdioEzr6Vea3RXuJ9ql7G66mK3Mmk8b88uTsEU0DgQibiPnhj57-Xddg","title":"PT anuncia candidatura de Fernando Haddad à Presidência no ...","snippet":"11 set. 2018 ... O prazo dado pelo TSE para o partido apresentar à Justiça Eleitoral o substituto 
de Lula terminava às 19h desta terça. Na chapa original ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AL8lKjOk4AvSk26yeM_CLTwL-pbhemUMarCpKtz2cjmDF5u-c1MKiPSNST_LKzGUhr5gIxpym10fbAyKebM_k5ztcDT4ccJLm7CiDn51AF8esXzqtzkfStIpvDMLDSzBEiJsY_vZ-n16Bq1rVLol6NPlA84ZHjMcdBFsRqyvAn1uWquy2kWhGINO24sm7grPZssXqNuqn3kE2VQWxUZrqU76ZfKon7_2sP_JnVoX616a7NqZ87w","title":"Pesquisa Ibope: Lula, 37%; Bolsonaro, 18%; Marina, 6%; Ciro, 5%","snippet":"20 ago. 2018 ... Em razão desse quadro jurídico, o Ibope pesquisou outro cenário, com o atual 
candidato a vice na chapa de Lula, Fernando Haddad."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/APDk4sNLn4v5wG7jZc1IMxmNqeoSmmu3CoLrgwpbMBTtGaGIPP6qNZCYoZJE-h7JvLCpES_LHdTgnGxzrSzi7qXlTfpcw_NWkH9lhvjaWJZmZCbHZM5jPivEEvXVa-370EEkKothZUYVdHjcJ_7Gd0FtSViBkVPdM1eplOHC2c-cxE5l-6iUJv-eIvsaBoTNH8m-N7KeL55C2RHIhWox4t_O_J6TePdYShasXr2p9CljniJyBnJg2gJqpDnpEg","title":"PT registra candidatura de Lula a presidente com ato em frente ao ...","snippet":"15 ago. 2018 ... Presidente do PT, Gleisi Hoffmann, entrega registro da candidatura de Lula a 
servidor do TSE — Foto: Nelson Jr./ASCOM/TSE ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AL8lKjPgDq40q5PA8lJ4zEjCmTIcjEId9kKJi_u79_HEROFIYaeDAza3mH3HEG5yW1W_0o0zUQTvFVUd9gRF64I5kZ9WUqwlrXBv3N0-ficFsPjhfdxo4H3CqkPvbjICafkJlZM2LnCTC7sKH_Wu7emMCZEki0XlYNuHyOOp114XJK5GbvR33QyBK3e9sVl9hoOpXsP44bNFtPy2ntiTo5ew58YJgSaB59sg1xrtW7PdaGKbcHDsg6bRyw","title":"Fachin nega pedido da defesa de Lula para suspender inelegibilidade","snippet":"6 set. 2018 ... Fachin nega pedido para suspender condenação de Lula no caso do ... o pedido 
da defesa do ex-presidente Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva para ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/APDk4sNLSBs3Q0r_tjyeUzsiMNvPILeN0DuMwwFLp7LWs11DJltsjOoj6lALGoBQ_HdCP5Pxa8rTJIe6SmXbEyi5iZ6CFNdrHxF0dwF2pf3J2UX0uIREc_MoNTGwEj53rHgTA21KV0gXTwNC4U-SPsRqFhI322S4AjnWeRr1h1ThAl1gJEEDEMSWm5-JEWPkSH4zrzjmbltEp_mKtMqG7PTLQdat0d_wIowh1wGQ3oMDrSM95XpVBOzvm2yg_t4wd5lh","title":"Entenda o que significa a impugnação da candidatura de Lula feita ...","snippet":"16 ago. 2018 ... As ações de impugnação ainda não impedem Lula de concorrer. O ministro Luís 
Roberto Barroso foi sorteado como relator do registro de ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AL8lKjMNo82Rv1wcvOpdbrQX7C7zD2sW7lFk0EBtJZZNs8rx0-tq2bYfyB_BsCGjt9fNa82lkSBH8Y4P_Of_uj9ryfcFxjIt_pbf49sLtNeAR529DWuje9j8Ps8-Z3qH2Wrh6N_Sb8P9eS88o26QKNLi94PDrPvFg7Q5Hv_i02L95dF_ZOV_avLu9sE0zzaX2l6hCQ1t-lXxegaf","title":"Comitê da ONU reafirma direito de Lula ser candidato, diz defesa ...","snippet":"10 set. 2018 ... Zanin afirmou que a defesa de Lula informará ao STF a nova decisão. Uma nova 
decisão do Comitê de Direitos Humanos da ONU reafirmou ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AFOm0uEggpSZolqYBXndC11CTFh4Bx4ojWZe-LQ4LpX3DXG401x0u8rk7AS41mhCRQqX6Ze7qXrfe0blgoqgeKkBvl2Roik39be5d8XX2HlZpL4bYGlC18o9U650kXjAkUn_vWc6YJRH5bUf1Hw15Zz4IlOE5idUbGmd0rnPl43DKMDReRgIHGc72dtcdXrz-ihJualpVoNpmfdaEQ","title":"Datafolha: sem Lula, Bolsonaro lidera e disputa fica acirrada ...","snippet":"31 jan. 2018 ... RIO — Pesquisa Datafolha divulgada nesta quarta-feira mostra que o ex-
presidente Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva , mesmo condenado pelo ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AFIPhzVJ3RSCVztRel4V7tABx7g_RC0G4uE43Wb1CdAxSf810y0LN7XN0iU1Ub5cj7-anDSrgzKJX9k1sx0tGFtzZhnTSyvCbAjhgqEHA-rrGWKMVAaHUXewZYj5IBY","title":"Após tiros e sob tensão, Lula encerra caravana em Curitiba horas ...","snippet":"28 mar. 2018 ... Poucas horas depois de a caravana do ex-presidente Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva 
chegar a Curitiba, ainda sob abalo pelo ataque que atingiu ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AJ-PF7wwGAYu07EXXfFG9u-ipk-azIf0t1m96KDvmxh5uuiAjuDg9QFlysO2nHCs9x0IRYCtpd_CphjEsDCZGMtxpcpzgeQdP-rJumaQVCIx6a2YCXteM6qFB6cerc5JSvbVfp5qTEwyDuB_R8gR9ZOK44cZxY2VIjPIAS4qsX-Wb2y0nSVXTtuM4BOZdPthrzxE8fXHoRc_zmYheufyS3FGXg","title":"Presidenciáveis e políticos comentam decisão de desembargador ...","snippet":"8 jul. 2018 ... O STF já havia negado HC para soltar Lula. Ele será solto neste domingo. A 
decisão foi monocrática, de um desembargador que foi filiado ao ..."},{"link":"https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AIQrb_7rn0-8BzJy4lp5vhkK_EOS2rsg2pNbSKHMcSAv7Zxb_T8GoBAYLmUZidgqaFo8Q0sgjTMTLhJe8ouJ0iutSoUi_6XA04aBJe0-d6df3YTmby4CBj7BfXDOYO4mHhO7iFv9i2pOooL4TWu-A5KQ7KqAk-GQP72jmClTQuBmZ5Frl6rlGiaW1A","title":"STJ nega habeas corpus preventivo por unanimidade e decide que ...","snippet":"6 mar. 2018 ... Na mesma decisão, os cinco ministros da Quinta Turma do STJ negaram um 
pedido extra da defesa para suspender a inelegibilidade de Lula ..."}]
```

EDIT: I have found out the error is the "snippet" tag, but I need it.

Comment: You have line breaks and possibly tabs in your `stringified` json. Can you try `json.replace(/\\n/g, '')` on the stringified json? The `JSON.stringify()` converts new lines and tabs to string and that seem to break the `ejs`. You can use this website to view line breaks and validate the above json https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: I tried other Json, and I got "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: The `json` you posted in your question has line breaks. The following SO question might be able to resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal, in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `JSON.parse()` is going to have a tough time with what you are feeding it as it just sees a simple string, not evaluated EJS or even valid JSON.

Perhaps something more along the lines of:

```
var json = <your-JSON-here>;
var news = ejs.render('<%- JSON.stringify(news) %>', {news: json});
```

Then if you want, you can always pull it back in as an object with `JSON.parse()`:

```
news = JSON.parse(news);
```